# POST Error when calling a backend function from frontend in React net::ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, express

I have created a website with React for frontend and nodejs express for backend. However when I try to call one of the backend functions from the frontend the request takes 2 minutes and then returns this error in the console:

```
POST http://evogenesis.co.uk:3000/nodeapp/api/register net::ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE
(anonymous) 
script.js:17

react_devtools_backend.js:2655 Error: TypeError: Failed to fetch
    at HTMLButtonElement.<anonymous> (<anonymous>:24:3)
```

This is the frontend function in my script.js file:

```js
// Register new user and save todo list to database
registerButton.addEventListener('click', function() {
  const email = emailInputRegister.value;
  currentuseremail = email;
  const todoList = [];
  const data = { email: email, todoList: todoList };
  fetch('http://evogenesis.co.uk:3000/nodeapp/api/register', {
    method: 'POST',
    headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' },
    body: JSON.stringify(data)
  })
  .then(response => {
      if (!response.ok) {
        throw new Error('Network response was not ok');
      }
      return response.json();
  })
  .then(data => {
      console.log('Success:', data);
  })
  .catch(error => {
      console.error('Error:', error);
      console.log(data);
  });
});
```

It calls a backend function in another file called app.py. It is located in a folder called nodeapp which is in the same directory as script.py (the public_html directory). Here is the entire app.js file:

```js
const express = require('express');
const mysql = require('mysql');
const cors = require('cors');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const path = require('path');

const app = express();
const port = 3000;

// Create connection to MySQL database
const connection = mysql.createConnection({
  host: '127.0.0.1',
  user: 'evogenes_shbc',
  password: 'mitsMysq27',
  database: 'evogenes_Users'
});

// Use bodyParser middleware to parse JSON data
app.use(bodyParser.json());

app.use(cors)
// Serve static files from public directory
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, '/')));

// Register new user and save todo list to database
app.post('/api/register', function() {
  const email = req.body.email;
  console.log(email);
  const todoList = JSON.stringify(req.body.todoList);
  console.log(todoList);
  const query = `INSERT INTO users (username, todo_list) VALUES (?, ?)`;
  console.log(query);
  connection.query(query, [email, todoList], function(error) {
    if (error) {
      console.error('Error registering user:', error);
      res.status(500).json({ error: error.message });
    } else {
      res.sendStatus(200);
    }
  });
  console.log("query done");
});

app.post('/api/save', function(req, res) {
    console.log("saving")

    const email = req.body.email;
    const todoList = JSON.stringify(req.body.todoList);
    const query = `UPDATE users SET todo_list = ? WHERE username = ?`;

    console.log(email);

    connection.query(query, [todoList, email], function(error) {
        if (error) {
            console.error('Error registering user:', error);
            res.sendStatus(500);
          } else {
            res.sendStatus(200);
        } 
    });
});

// Start server
app.listen(port, function() {
  console.log(`Server listening on port sdfsd`);
});
```

The whole thing is run on a Node.js app that I setup through my web hosting provider (ifastnet). I have started the app via the GUI provided, but I though I could also try to run it via the terminal they provide but when i run the node app.js in the nodeapp directory I get this error:

```
events.js:160
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^

Error: listen EADDRINUSE :::3000
    at Object.exports._errnoException (util.js:1020:11)
    at exports._exceptionWithHostPort (util.js:1043:20)
    at Server._listen2 (net.js:1271:14)
    at listen (net.js:1307:10)
    at Server.listen (net.js:1403:5)
    at EventEmitter.listen (/home/evogenes/nodevenv/public_html/nodeapp/10/lib/node_modules/express/lib/application.js:635:24)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/evogenes/public_html/nodeapp/app.js:64:5)
    at Module._compile (module.js:577:32)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:586:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:494:32)
```

And when I try to make a request to the http://evogenesis.co.uk/nodeapp/api/register address via postman it throws this error:

```
{
    "status": "error",
    "message": "Incomplete response received from application"
}
```

I have tried checking the error logs (as far as I know, ifastnet error messages for node.js apps are sent to a log file you specify. However, the log file contains only this:

```
App 11205 output: Server listening on port sdfsd
App 8735 output: Server listening on port sdfsd
App 31095 output: Server listening on port sdfsd
App 10462 output: Server listening on port sdfsd
App 5055 output: Server listening on port sdfsd
```

Also no new records are being added to the table on the mysql database (also provided by ifastnet). Why is this problem being caused and how can I solve it? I can provide the full code for the HTML page and the rest for the javascript frontend if needed.

Answer (score 1):

listen EADDRINUSE :::3000 this error means that your port is already used for some other process, so simply change your port in app.listen() to be something else, 8080 for example

Comment: Ok so the terminal issue is fixed - when I run the script it gives me the server listening message. However I'm still getting the same issue when i try to run the function (via clicking the button) in the browser: 
script.js:17          POST http://evogenesis.co.uk:3000/nodeapp/api/register net::ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE
(anonymous) @ script.js:17
react_devtools_backend.js:2655 Error: TypeError: Failed to fetch
    at HTMLButtonElement.<anonymous> (<anonymous>:24:3)

and it still takes 2 minutes until failing.

Comment: I'm also confused about whether I need to run it in terminal or not. I seem to get the same error regardless - can I just let it run with the node.js app setup function provided by ifastnet? Are there any advantages to running it in the terminal?